# understanding if check in extend function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make sense of the jquery extend function, basically have a look at the below code:

```
function () {
    var src, copyIsArray, copy, name, options, clone, target = arguments[0] || {},
        i = 1,
        length = arguments.length,
        deep = false;

    // Handle a deep copy situation
    if (typeof target === "boolean") {
        deep = target;

        // skip the boolean and the target
        target = arguments[i] || {};
        i++;
    }

    // Handle case when target is a string or something (possible in deep copy)
    if (typeof target !== "object" && !jQuery.isFunction(target)) {
        target = {};
    }

    // extend jQuery itself if only one argument is passed
    if (i === length) {
        target = this;
        i--;
    }

    for (; i < length; i++) {
        // Only deal with non-null/undefined values
        if ((options = arguments[i]) != null) {
            // Extend the base object
            for (name in options) {
                src = target[name];
                copy = options[name];

                // Prevent never-ending loop
                if (target === copy) {
                    continue;
                }

                // Recurse if we're merging plain objects or arrays
                if (deep && copy && (jQuery.isPlainObject(copy) || (copyIsArray = jQuery.isArray(copy)))) {
                    if (copyIsArray) {
                        copyIsArray = false;
                        clone = src && jQuery.isArray(src) ? src : [];

                    } else {
                        clone = src && jQuery.isPlainObject(src) ? src : {};
                    }

                    // Never move original objects, clone them
                    target[name] = jQuery.extend(deep, clone, copy);

                    // Don't bring in undefined values
                } else if (copy !== undefined) {
                    target[name] = copy;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Return the modified object
    return target;
}
```

Now I understand most part of the code expect a `if` check I.E. the below line of code :

```
if (target === copy) {
                    continue;
                }
```

what on earth is this line really checking for ??

if you have a closer look at a few lines of code before this check , you see the below ::

```
if ((options = arguments[i]) != null) {
            // Extend the base object
            for (name in options) {
                src = target[name];
                copy = options[name];

                // Prevent never-ending loop
                if (target === copy) {
                    continue;
                }
```

Options is assigned a value and is checked for not being `null`, after that a `for..in` loop iterates over the keys of options and then you see the values of `target[name]` and `options[name]` being assigned to temporary variables.

I basically understand the background, but I still don't understand the code below:

```
                // Prevent never-ending loop
                if (target === copy) {
                    continue;
                }
```

Can somebody explain what is the above line doing?  I also don't understand the comment above that says

```
// Prevent never-ending loop.
```

**P.S.** :: for simplicity sake , lets assume that ::

```
target = {};
```

Comment: It avoids cycles when deeply extending an object with itself. In other words, it handles the case `var foo = {}; $.extend(true, foo, { bar: foo });`.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi , interesting , but i still don't get what the if is checking for .

Comment: Well, you say you *understand most of the code except that `if` statement*. If my previous comment didn't help, you may be optimistic on *most*. Are you actually asking about what `target` and `copy` actually are? Or is there something I'm missing?